# PHP Editing of Files Via FTP

Tags: php, ftp

Below is a script I am using to modify some files with placeholder strings.  The `.htaccess` file sometimes gets truncated.  It's about 2,712 bytes in size before editing and will vary in size after editing depending on the length of the domain name.  When it gets truncated, it ends up around 1,400 bytes in size.

```
$d_parts = explode('.', $vals['domain']);
$ftpstring = 'ftp://' . $vals['username']
        . ':' . $vals['password']
        . '@' . $vals['ftp_server']
        . '/' . $vals['web_path']
;
$stream_context = stream_context_create(array('ftp' => array('overwrite' => true)));

$htaccess = file_get_contents($ftpstring . '.htaccess');
$htaccess = str_replace(array('{SUB}', '{DOMAIN}', '{TLD}'), $d_parts, $htaccess);
file_put_contents($ftpstring . '.htaccess', $htaccess, 0, $stream_context);

$constants = file_get_contents($ftpstring . 'constants.php');
$constants = str_replace('{CUST_ID}', $vals['cust_id'], $constants);
file_put_contents($ftpstring . 'constants.php', $constants, 0, $stream_context);
```

Is there a bug in `file_get_contents()`, `str_replace()`, or `file_put_contents()`?  I have done quite a bit of searching and haven't found any reports of this happening for others.

Is there a better method of accomplishing this?

**SOLUTION**

Based on Wrikken's response, I started using file pointers with ftp_f(get|put), but ended up with zero length files being written back.  I stopped using file pointers and switched to ftp_(get|put), and now everything seems to be working:

```
$search = array('{SUB}', '{DOMAIN}', '{TLD}', '{CUST_ID}');
$replace = explode('.', $vals['site_domain']);
$replace[] = $vals['cust_id'];
$tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'config');

foreach (array('.htaccess', 'constants.php') as $file_name) {
    $remote_file = $dest_path . $file_name;
    if (!@ftp_get($conn_id, $tmpfname, $remote_file, FTP_ASCII, 0)) {
        echo $php_errormsg;
    } else {
        $contents = file_get_contents($tmpfname);
        $contents = str_replace($search, $replace, $contents);
        file_put_contents($tmpfname, $contents);
        if (!@ftp_fput($conn_id, $remote_file, $tmpfname, FTP_ASCII, 0)) {
            echo $php_errormsg;
        }
    }
}

unlink($tmpfname);
```

Comment: What does the truncated version of the file look like?

Comment: @Pekka - It's simply missing the last part of the file.  I have several lines of `AddType` declarations and truncation usually ends up in the middle of one of those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With either passive of active ftp, I've never had much luck file using the file-family of functions with the `ftp` wrappers, usually with that kind of truncation problem. I usually just revert to the [ftp functions](http://nl2.php.net/ftp) with passive transfers, which do make it harder to switch, but work flawlessly for me.

Comment: Do you have example code for a get->edit->put type of process?

Comment: Using a tandem of `tempnam` for a temporary file, and `ftp_fget`, altering the data in your temporary file, and an `ftp_fput` when you're finished would do the trick.

Comment: I updated my post. I am ending up with zero length files now.

Comment: You probably forgot to use `fseek` to set the pointer back to beginning in that case... (`fseek($handle,0)`), but indeed, ftp_put/get would also work.